# How do I display an additional partial view when a user clicks a button on the main view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want to click the button on the "main view" and populate the partial view in its own . Updated

I have a main view:

```
 @{
using (Ajax.BeginForm("PastClaims", "Claim", FormMethod.Post, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "update_panel", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
    <legend>Submit a Claim</legend>
    @Html.EditorForModel()
    <div class="controls">
        <input id="btnCheckForClaims" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit Claim" />
    </div>


    }
```

I need to click the submit button then display this other view:
If I do below then on the page on the initial load it displays the div

```
 <div id="update_panel">@Html.Partial("PastClaims")</div>
```

If I leave the div blank then I get a new partial view.

```
  <div id="update_panel"></div>
```

if I leave them null like darrin suggested:

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm("PastClaims", "Claim", FormMethod.Post, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "update_panel", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
```

I am redirected to the same page (what I want) but the additional partial view is not displayed.

Thanks to Darrin below to get me this far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use an `Ajax.BeginForm` in this case:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(null, null, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "update_panel", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }, new { @class = "form-horizontal"}))
{
    @Html.EditorForModel()
    <div class="controls">
        <input id="btnOpenPartialView" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="OpenPartialView" />
    </div>
}

<div id="update_panel">
    @Html.Partial("PartialView")
</div>
```

and then the corresponding controller action will return the partial view:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction() 
{
    // some processing ...
    return PartialView("PartialView");
}
```

For `Ajax.*` helpers to work don't forget to include the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` script:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Should  the three nulls be the names of my Controller and Model and something else. Or are they purposley null?

Comment: The first is the controller action, the second is the controller name and the third is additional route values. If you leave the controller and the action null then it will use the same as the one used to render the view, except that with the POST verb.

Comment: When I use this I am redirected to a new page with the partial view on it. I was hoping to add a div on the current view that Displayed the partial view. Did I miss a step somewhere?

Comment: Yes, you missed the last step: `For Ajax.* helpers to work don't forget to include the jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js script.`

Comment: I have that in my code currently. I am trying to make the "PartialView" appear in a new <div> tag on my "MainView" page. The above code works very well only instead of adding the new button and message to the original view I get an entirely new page

Comment: Make sure that this script is included **after** jquery as it depends on jquery. Also ensure that you do not have any errors in your javascript debug console. Also the div must exist initially. It could be empty: `<div id="update_panel"></div>` but it must exist. When you submit the form it will be populated with the result of the PartialView returned by this controller action.

Comment: No errors in my java script window, Script tag is before Ajax declaration. Div already exists. I am still getting the partial view on a new page instead of in the div on the main view

Answer (score 0):

`@Html.Partial` is server code, if you want load partial after submit, then try this:

```
$("form").on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);

    $.ajax({
       url: form.attr('action'),
       type: form.attr('method'),
       data: form.serialize(),
       success: function(r) {
           $('#update_panel').html(r);
       }
    });
});
```